# Use WPF component from external .exe

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, external, guptateamdeveloper

Here's the situation:

We have an existing .NET executable that contains an application using WPF components (dialogs and forms). This executable was created using Gupta Team Developer 6.1, but I'm not sure that is relevant to my question. We'd like to re-use some of these forms in a C#-application, but this is proving difficult.

When we include the external components, either in XAML or by instantiating them in code, they *look* OK (i.e. fields, buttons, layout etc.), but the event wiring seems to be missing. Nothing happens when pressing buttons and tables/grids are empty.

I've read previous articles on this site on using external WPF components, but they all mention external assemblies compiled as control libraries. Are we trying to do something that's not really possible?

P.S As an experiment we've tried to instantiate the App-object from the executable directly and this brings up a fully functional version of the entire application (well, duh), but we'd really like to be able to pick and choose from the individual forms/dialogs.

Comment: Do the dialogs depend on some global resources (e.g. in the `App.xaml`)? Are there binding errors in the debug output?

Comment: The App.xaml in the source executable is empty apart from setting the StartupUri property (which is overridden in its InitializeComponent btw)

We do get a fair amount of System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException when instatiating the external components, but since we can't debug into the code we haven't been able to pinpoint them

Comment: And why can't you debug the code? Don't you have the code?

Comment: I have the source code for the original Team Developer application, but since it's been compiled to .NET I can't debug into it without using a tool like .NET reflector, which I don't have access to at the moment. I'm not sure how useful that would be anyway, as I'm not that proficient with IL yet :/

Comment: Reflector decompiles IL to C# or VB.Net, so you don't have to know IL.